# He washed dishes three times vs They washed dishes once

Tags: sentence-choice

There are men, A, B and C. They each washed dishes once. Can I rephrase it as ‘he washed dishes three times’ or ‘one of them washed dishes three times’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your phrases

> ‘he washed dishes three times’

means *A man washed the dishes 3 times. We are specifying that a certain person, "he", was the one that washed them*. The fact that he "washed dishes" and not specifically "washed the dishes" Leaves us with a very vague description. What dishes? where? when? it could mean in the whole of his life he only washed dishes three times.

> ‘one of them washed dishes three times’?

means *A man washed the dishes 3 times but we are not specifying the specific person. However we do know it was just one person.* Again it is a vague description with the implication already discussed above.

---

Therefore to answer your question

> There are men, A, B and C. They each washed dishes once.

**No it cannot be replaced with either of your phrases shown above.**

---

There are men, A, B and C. They each washed dishes once.

> The dishes had been washed three times, once each by the three men.

Some specific dishes have been washed three times, each time by a different one of the group of three men.

Answer (score 0):

> **They each** [or **each man**] washed dishes once.

This is a perfectly fine statement to make.

> He washed dishes three times.

This is grammatically okay but does not accurately describe the situation. "He" refers to *a single man*. It is not the case that one single man did three sets of dishes.

> One of them washed dishes three times.

This is the same exact problem as above. It is not the case that *only one of them* washed dishes.

Comment: Then should I say ‘take three showers’ not ‘take a shower three times’?

Comment: Because ‘take a shower three times’ means ‘take only one shower three times’?

Comment: @user28383 you would never say "take a shower three times" under any circumstances because you can only take any given shower one time. If you are talking about yourself on a very hot day, you say "I took three showers that day." If you are talking about three men taking showers, each in their own bathroom, you say "they each took a shower." If the three men all showered at once (like in the locker room of a gym) you *might* say "they all took a shower" and probably you would add "...together" to be clear.